# OS X install z3 with z3types.Z3Exception: 'init(Z3_LIBRARY_PATH)

Tags: python, macos, z3

I'm trying to install z3 locally on my MAC, When I try the example, I got the exception:
z3types.Z3Exception: 'init(Z3_LIBRARY_PATH), which is weird, because I've already linked it.

Here is how I installed it:

```
>> git clone https://git01.codeplex.com/z3 -b unstable
>> cd z3
>> python scripts/mk_make.py
>> sudo make install
```

It says "z3 was successfully installed", but with 3 warnings.
Then I link the lib:

```
>> export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH = /Users/my_acount/Documents/z3/build:${DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH}
```

when I try the example by

> > python example.py

it returns the exception: z3types.Z3Exception: 'init(Z3_LIBRARY_PATH)

Anybody know why?

Comment: Just to make sure: You did change into the build directory, i.e., 'cd build', after running mk_make.py, right?

Comment: Also, when exporting DYLD_*_PATH, my OSX complains about the spaces before and after =.

Comment: @ChristophWintersteiger, yes I did changed the build directory after running mk_make.py, and I'm sure the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH has been correctly added, because I've checked by echo $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: Hmm. Is it possible that there is a typo in your export statement where it says "my_acount" with a single c instead of a double c?

Comment: Also, which version of OSX and XCode do you use?

Comment: @ChristophWintersteiger, not the my_account name problem. I'm using OSX version 10.9.3, Xcode 5.1.1. I fixed the problem by export the path of lib and bin to .bash_profile. And maybe do the export right after make. Anyway, thanks Christoph

Comment: Hmm strange, Python should be happy with the path added to PYTHONPATH as the install instructions say. Anyways, good that you got it working!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/43055335/781723