# Z3 Python bindings: init(Z3_LIBRARY_PATH) must be invoked before using Z3-python

Tags: python, z3, z3py, library-path

I installed the [Z3 theorem prover](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/wiki) on Linux, and am using its Python bindings (Z3Py).  I tried to test a minimal example, but I immediately got the following error:

```
z3.z3types.Z3Exception: init(Z3_LIBRARY_PATH) must be invoked before using Z3-python
```

How do I fix this and get up and running with Z3?

I'm not quite sure what that error message means.  The Z3 documentation and tutorials don't seem to say anything about this or about `init()`, and the [Z3-Python docs](https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/z3.html) don't list any function called `init()`.

In more detail, here is what I tried (lightly excerpted):

```
$ python
Python 2.7.13 (default, Jan 12 2017, 17:59:37)
>>> from z3 import *
>>> Int('x')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/z3/z3core.py", line 22, in lib
    raise Z3Exception("init(Z3_LIBRARY_PATH) must be invoked before using Z3-python")
z3.z3types.Z3Exception: init(Z3_LIBRARY_PATH) must be invoked before using Z3-python
```

I tried setting an environment variable called `Z3_LIBRARY_PATH` before running Python, on the off chance that would help, but it made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

After importing the Z3 libraries, call

```
init('/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/z3')
```

before invoking any other Z3 APIs.  You might need to adjust the path: change it to the path where `libz3.so` is found.  (Try `locate libz3.so` to find it, if it's not in an obvious place.)

Example usage:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.13 (default, Jan 12 2017, 17:59:37)
>>> from z3 import *
>>> init('/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/z3')
>>> Int('x')
x
```